# Sql server timeout after successful ODBC connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, networking, odbc, lan

I have 4 systems in LAN three systems are working perfectly to access sql server on LAN. On forth system ODBC connection is successfully created and tested but when i am trying to login using Management studio it gives error timeout expired. What can be the possible reason. Troubleshooting done

- Lan working perfect.
- Disable antivirus.
- ODBC test.

I thought it can be issue of windows so tried formatting it too. What can b the possible issue behind this.

Comment: why negative vote.??

Answer (score 0):

System by default try TCP/IP network protocal and query timeout in 15 seconds and ODBC works on named pipes. To solve this issue add np before server name for named pipes like np:servername